# Update Some part of a Column based on matched pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a configuration table where application url get stored. Application is on various server and everytime when we need to setup a new server, we need to update the values by selecting and running a while loop in sql. Scenerios is like

Table : Configuration
Values

```
Id | key |  DefaultUrl

1  | Key1 | www.xxx.com/something1

2  | key2 | www.xxx.com/something2

3  | key3 | www.xxx.com/something3
```

There are many more keys on this pattern and some other table too. As this is a legacy software i can not change the structure.

Whenever i need to setup a new server then i need to replace the url part from `www.xxx.com` to `www.yyy.com`. To achieve this i do something like

- Write a select query on like pattern
- Loop through the data and replace the data in every row one by one.

So right now i am looking a better approach to achieve the same. Please help!

Comment: hawe you tried already anything?

Comment: nothing much coming in my mind or in google, i just used this select and loop approach

Comment: "i can not change the structure" - what about a new base table(s) with the static and dynamic parts in separate columns, then a `VIEW` to put the split parts back together again in a single column, where the `VIEW` has the same name as the original (now dropped) table?

Comment: @onedaywhen thanks...this was my original idea..i already discussed the same...hopefully we are going to do that in future...until then I have to work what i already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible problem is when `www.xxx.com` is somewhere in the middle of the url and it shouldn't be replaced. Use some forbidden in url character  `' '` for example.

```
UPDATE [Configuration Values]
SET DefaultUrl = replace(' '+DefaultUrl, ' www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.com')
WHERE DefaultUrl LIKE 'www.xxx.com%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function. Try like this,

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    id INT
    ,[key] VARCHAR(10)
    ,DefaultUrl VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES (
    1
    ,'Key1'
    ,'www.xxx.com/something1'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'key2'
    ,'www.xxx.com/something2'
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,'key3'
    ,'www.xxx.com/something3'
    )

SELECT replace(DefaultUrl, 'www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.com')
FROM @Table

UPDATE @Table
SET DefaultUrl = replace(DefaultUrl, 'www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.com')
where .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
insert into configuration (key, defaulturl, . . . )
    select key, replace(defaulturl, 'www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.com')
    from configuration
    where defaulturl like '%www.xxx.com%';
```

This will replicate the key values for xxx for yyy in the configuration table.